# Unity3d button is clicked when it should not be clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a simple 2d pong game. I finished everything now the only problem I have is that the GUI exit or restart button clicks are being recorded when it should not be recorded. Lets say both players fingers are on the screen and they move them so one players finger is 25 units from the button on the x axis and the others -25. These 2 finger touches somehow record as one finger touch in the middle of the screen where my exit button is and the app closes. I have 2 scripts for player controls one for Player 1 and other for player 2

```
var speed : float = 10;

        function Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        var touchDeltaPos:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        if(Input.touchCount>1)
        var touchDeltaPos2:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
        if(touchDeltaPos.x<Screen.width/2)
        {
            if(touchDeltaPos.y > Screen.height/2)
            {
                rigidbody2D.velocity.y = 1*speed;
            }
            else rigidbody2D.velocity.y = -1*speed;
        }
        else if(touchDeltaPos2.x<Screen.width/2&&Input.touchCount>1)
        {
            if(touchDeltaPos2.y > Screen.height/2)
            {
                rigidbody2D.velocity.y = 1*speed;
            }
            else rigidbody2D.velocity.y = -1*speed;
        }
    }
    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        rigidbody2D.velocity.y = 0;
    rigidbody2D.velocity.x=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your buttons are, but in any case how about making a buffer so it won't be touched by accident like

```
width = Screen.width/2 - 100
```

or minus 100 whichever works, the buffer is supposed to take in account the width and height of the finger as well

**EDIT**
When I say buffer, it means a temporary storage like a variable. So for the code you could do:

```
var buffer:int = 100;
(touchDeltaPos.x < Screen.width/2 - buffer)
```

Now why do this? Well, the buffer gives more room for the player's playing area from the exit button.

Comment: Since I'm new to Unity3D how do you make a buffer ?